# How can i access remote ports other than 80 from my home network?

Tags: networking, router, port

I am trying to access a remote website running on port 8000. From my home network i cannot (it simply times out), but i can access it from my phone's 3G network.

My ISP is Bezeq International and the router is a Cisco Linksys E1000. I disabled the firewall but that still didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a remote site FROM your home network and it fails? Your Linksys shouldn't be blocking any outbound traffic... Assuming this isn't a PC or other internal problem since it works from a different Internet connection, the problem is with your ISP,  not your equipment or configuration.

Comment: So basically i need to contact the ISP and ask them to unblock traffic?

Comment: If it works with a different ISP, meaning your mobile data, then the problem isn't your equipment. So, yes, contact your carrier.

Comment: I will let you know if this works after i get around to contacting the ISP.

Comment: Interestingly, without even talking to the ISP, it randomly started working.